# Connected CW complex, isomorphism?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, group-cohomology

Let $\pi$ be a group and let $K(\pi, 1)$ be a connected CW complex such that $\pi_1(K(\pi, 1)) = \pi$ and $\pi_q(K(\pi, 1)) = 0$ for $q \neq 1$. My question is, are $H_*(K(\pi, 1);A)$  and $\text{Tor}_*^{\mathbb{Z}[\pi]}(A, \mathbb{Z})$ necessarily isomorphic?

Comment: If I am not making mistake, since the universal cover of $K(\pi,1)$ has the cellular chain as projective resolution of $\mathbb{Z}$ over $\mathbb{Z}[\pi]$, you want to show that $(-\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[\pi]}\mathbb{Z})\otimes_\mathbb{Z}A$(computes the cellular chain of $H_*$) is isomorphic to $-\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[\pi]}A$(computes $Tor$).

Comment: @MingcongZeng, this is a full answer, you should write it as such.

Comment: Yes, these groups are necessarily isomorphic, and the story of this (and the interpretation of group cohomology as Ext) played a critical role of the development of homological algebra in the 40's-50's (http://www.math.uiuc.edu/K-theory/0245/survey.pdf).

Comment: @TylerLawson This article is really awesome!!!

Answer (score 2):

I've a small worry that it might depend on what category your $A$ lives in.  If $A$ is just an abelian group, then:

From the [User's Guide](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511626289)

> **Theorem** (Cartan-Leray) for a free and proper action of $\pi$ on $X$ there is a spectral sequence converging strongly $E \Rightarrow H_*(X/\pi,A)$ with $E^2_{p,q} \simeq H_p(\pi,H_q(X,A)) $

In particular, $H_p(\pi,-)$ is your $\operatorname{Tor}_p^{\mathbb{Z}[\pi]}(-,\mathbb{Z})$.  In the Particular Case of Interest, $X\simeq\hat{K}(\pi,1)$ is contractible, so that $H_*(X,A)$ would seem to be just $A$, in degree zero.  Consequently, the spectral sequence collapses on the second page; there are no extension problems to solve.

---

I readily admit there is something unsatisfying/disturbing in this argument: the tool is heavier and more blunt than the result we really want. It might be more fun/enlightening to construct $K(\pi,1)$ from $\pi$ as a $\triangle$-complex and then write down its cellular complex of $A$-valued chains, vs. writing a resolution of $\mathbb{Z}$ as a trivial $\pi$-module and tensoring with $A$.  Work on paper, be careful, and consult any mathematical friends in your neighborhood.

Comment: Every choice of resolution of $\mathbb{Z}$ as a $\mathbb{Z}[\pi]$-module gives a different (but homotopy equivalent) model of $K(\pi,1)$. One easy way to see this is working simplicially and then using the Dold-Kan correspondence. I agree this is a bit heavy handed. Another way is to see that $K(\pi,1)$ is modeled by the Bar construction just like group homology and that one is the free abelian group on the other.

Comment: Yes, the Bar construction was the one I had in mind... there aren't *many* constructions of a resolution one can describe without knowing which group $\pi$ is.